# How can I define a lambda function with a generic argument and return type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Given this TypeScript snippet:

```
type Handler<Type> = {
  <Param extends unknown> (value:Param, ...args:unknown[]):Type;
}

type Handlers<Type> = {
  [x:string]: Handler<Type>;
}

const strHandlers:Handlers<string> = {
  // value should be a numeric, returning string
  foo: (value, precision) => value.toFixed(precision),
  
  // value should be a Date instance, returning string 
  bar: value => value.toSIOString(),
}
```

How can I make these two properties to specify what type is the argument `value`? At this point, both arguments `value` are of type `Param extends unknown`.

I'm not certain what I should do, so I tried this:

```
const strHandlers:Handlers<string> = {
  foo: (value:number, precision:number) => value.toFixed(precision),
}
```

But it still complaints that `value` is incompatible with `value`, cannot assign `Param` to `number`.

#### Edit

I also tried this:

```
const foo:Handler<string> = (value:number, precision:number) =>
   value.toFixed(precision);

const str = foo(3.14192, 2);
```

and, while `foo(3.1415, 2)` does not show any error, the `const foo` does. It complaints about being impossible to assign `Param` to type `number`.

Comment: You want the key to determine the type of `value` ?

Comment: That code snippet is confusing and unlikely to represent anything useful to you (you probably don't want `Param` to be declared where it is, the `any` for `...args` is going to be unsafe); could you back up and actually describe your use case? How do you plan to call the functions?  Right now I'd be inclined to just write [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB4MzW), without any kind of type annotation, unless some use case necessitated something else.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I can see how the the snippet can be confusing, I was simply trying to be less cryptic. I want to specify the actual types for each key of `Handlers<Type>`. I have updated the question to remove that confusion.

Comment: Note that the first two comments were from two different people. I still don't understand the goal; you don't need to annotate in any of your examples; what's wrong with just letting the compiler infer, as shown in [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wOxbRN))? If you need some kind of typing to guarantee that the return types are all `string` (or some other specified type) while still allowing different inputs, I'd use a generic type and a helper function [like this playground link shows](//tsplay.dev/mbK4dW). If that doesn't meet your needs, please demonstrate a failed use case.